# Update some elements in my HashSet

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a `Set` of `MyObject` retrieved from database in Hibernate way.

```
Set<MyObject> dbObjects = dbService.getMyObjects();
```

Then, I got another `Map` of `MyObject` from client:

`Map<String, MyObject> newObjects = getNewObjectsFromClient();`

`MyObject` has a attribute named `name` .

I want to **replace** the elements in `dbObjects` (it's a `Set`) with the `newObjects` (it's a `Map`) that have the same `name`. I ended up with the following code, but I get stuck…

```
Collection<MyObject> newCollection = newObjects.values();
for(MyObject newObj : newCollection){
      String newObjName = newObj.getName();
     for(MyObject dbObj : dbObjects){
        if(dbObj.getName.equals(newObjName)){
            //Here, I intend to replace the dbObj with newObj in dbObjects Set  
              //but I feel it is not efficient with this nested for loop 
             //& I am currently iterating the dbObjects, I can't replace element now        
        }
    }
}
```

I feel the above code is inefficient . Is there any better solution to update the `Set<MyObject>` ?

(Please don't recommend me to create a new Set to hold the updated elements (for hibernate reason), I only want to update the exising `dbObjects` **Set** )

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know hibernate. So, my answer may be incorrect.

```
Collection<MyObject> replaceObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
for(MyObject newObj : newCollection){
     String newObjName = newObj.getName();
     Iterator itr = dbObjects.iterator();
     while(itr.hasNext()) {
        MyObject dbObj = itr.next();
        if(dbObj.getName.equals(newObjName)){
            replaceObjects.add(dbObj);
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
    dbObjects.addAll(repalceObjects);
}
```